# How to share information between multiple blocs [accessing other blocs from another bloc]

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

Iam developing a flutter application using bloc as my state management, can someone please help me, that how can i use information with in another bloc, for example i have a projectsbloc, that holds the information of my projects in its state, and upon tapping on anyone of the project, the projectsbloc has a state that holds the selected project data in its state, now since i had tapped on the project, it will navigate to my projectwizardpage, now here i want to use the projectsbloc's selectedproject state, so that i can use it for all my work.

[i have some data in a state of one bloc, and i want to use it in another bloc, so that i can use it in my ui]

```
late workitemsBloc _workitemsbloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    // workitemsBloc().add(getProjectDetails());
    _workitemsbloc = workitemsBloc(
      userProfileBloc: BlocProvider.of<UserProfileBloc>(context),
      assignedProjectsBloc: BlocProvider.of<AssignedProjectsBloc>(context),
    );

    // Delay the execution and then dispatch the getProjectDetails event
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      if (mounted) {
        // Check if the widget is still mounted before dispatching the event
        _workitemsbloc.add(getProjectDetails());
      }
    });


    super.initState();
  }
```

this is how iam initializing the other bloc in my ui and calling the event, that fetches the data from the projectsbloc state.

but iam getting null at the end each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class that will act as `Data reciever/streamer`.
that can accept incoming data and broadcast it.
it's a like a man in the middle between the two Blocs.
you can listen to these changes and get broadcasted data

```
class DataRepository {
  final _dataStreamController = StreamController<String>();

  // Sink for adding data to the stream
  Sink<String> get dataSink => _dataStreamController.sink;

  // Stream for listening to data changes
  Stream<String> get dataStream => _dataStreamController.stream;
}
```

you will have instance of `DataRepository` class in Blocs you want them to connect together

let's say that `BlocA` is the Bloc which will send data to `BlocB`

```
class BlocA {
  final DataRepository _dataRepository;

  BlocA(this._dataRepository);

  void updateData(String newData) {
    _dataRepository.dataSink.add(newData);
  }
}
```

using `add()` method on sink to push the data.
and here is `BlocB` code that will listen to these data.

```
class BlocB {
  final DataRepository _dataRepository;

  BlocB(this._dataRepository) {
    _dataRepository.dataStream.listen((data) {
      // Handle data changes in BlocB
      print('BlocB received data: $data');
    });
  }
}
```

i'm using `listen()` method to listen to data added by `sink` from BlocA
and do whatever you want

here is a real example of that

```
class AuthStatusBloc extends Bloc<AuthStatusEvent, AuthStatusState> {
  static final _controller = StreamController<AuthStatusEvent>.broadcast();
  static Stream<AuthStatusEvent> get streamChannel => _controller.stream;
  static StreamSink<AuthStatusEvent> get sink => _controller.sink;


  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    sink.close();
    _controller.close();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

in this example i send stream of events to `AuthBloc` to update layout if user is logged.

it's important to close streams after opening it.
in Bloc do that using close method